# C# DateTime.Now() to JSON, to C++

Tags: c++, json, c++11

I have an application written in C# (Client) which sends some data via UDP to another application, written in C++ (Server).

The client sends a JOSON serialized object, `myPacket`, to the server, however, one of the properties of `myPacket` is a `DateTime` whos value has been set to `DateTime.Now()`.

Now, I am able to parse the JSON received by the server and can get the `DateTime` property (which is obviously still a string), but I have no idea how to convert it from this string to a `timestamp`... later, I will be serializing this data again, but with an updated `timestamp`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: @Amit The serialized JSON timestamp? My JSON looks like this: {"Id":"3ef7a760-5962-41d0-93f3-a591016f6e7f","TimeStamp":"\/Date(1453155466661)\/"}